# Convert column as column header with count of column values

Tags: python, pandas, count

Image A is my dataframe with two columns which as multiple values, I want convert this val column as my header for columns as shown in Image B and add count  of values for each user. I tried using pandas groupby and count but not able to get expected result.

```
lst = ['UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC', 'UserD','UserB', 'UserC']
lst2 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y','X','Z'] 

dm = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), columns =['Name', 'val']) 
dm['count']= 1
dm.groupby(['Name','val']).count()
```

[image: Image A, This is my dataset]

[image: Image B, this is expected output]

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['val'])` or `pd.groupby('Name')['val'].value_counts().unstack()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `unstack`:

```
dm.groupby(['Name','val']).count()['count'].unstack('val', fill_value='')
```

Output:

```
val    X  Y  Z
Name          
UserA  1      
UserB  1  1   
UserC        2
UserD     1
```